# Can't assign value to variable from doInBackground to main class

Tags: java, android, variable-assignment

I have a android class where I initialise my variables:

```
public class myClass extends Activity {
String itemIdString;
...
}
```

then I invoke  `AssyncTask` in my `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next_item_caller);

            Log.d("Before " +itemName);
            new getItemNumber().execute();
            Log.d("After" +itemName);
            ...
     return "success";
    }
```

In `AssyncTask` I parse JSON object and assign values to variables:

```
 class getItemNumber extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("getItemNumber", "On pre-execute");
    }

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
//parse here
itemIdString = c.getString(TAG_ITEM_ID);
Log.d(TAG, itemIdString);
}
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("getItemNumber", "on Post-Execute");
    }
```

My  Log in `AssyncTask` prints values as supposed to, but in `onCreate` *before* and *after* values are null? How should I assign those strings so that I can access them from other methods as well? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` runs on another thread.

`onCreate` runs on the UI thread.

Therefore when you call `AsyncTask.execute()` you don't wait for it to finish and move on with your next line which is

```
Log.d("After" +itemName);
```

To detect **when** `doInBackground` has finished, you have a convenience callback method `onPostExecute`:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        // doInBackground finished, use your variable now
    }

}
```

Comment: @Emily just move `Log.d("After" +itemName);` to the `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Sorry for bad question formatting, I edited it again. What I meant is how can I assign value to `String itemIdString` and access it from `onCreate`?

Comment: @Emily if you want to access it from `onCreate` you shouldn't be using an `AsyncTask`. Please read on the documentation and the whole principle of Threads.

Answer (score 1):

Return the string value from the doInBackgroind method and then assign it to itemIdString in the onPostExecute method which runs on the main thread

```
class getItemNumber extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("getItemNumber", "On pre-execute");
    }

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    //parse here
    return c.getString(TAG_ITEM_ID);
}

 protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
   super.onPostExecute(result);
    //assign itemIdString here
   itemIdString = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way to do this is that you can check status of your `AsyncTask` as follows:

in `onCreate()`, you can check the status of AysncTask like this one:

```
MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myAsyncTask.execute();

if(myAsyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        // MyAsyncTask completed. assign your variable now    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it didn't help since I want to assign variable *from* the `AsyncTask` *to* the main thread

Comment: @Emily then why don't you use onPostExecute()?

Comment: is that an answer or a quesiton

Comment: @Emily question for you. answer for me.